# N-Array Tree Some Logic Cant UnderStand

Tags: algorithm, logic

I Read Wikipedia Defination which is

> A full n-ary tree is a n-ary tree where within each level every node
>   has either 0 or n children.

**So I am confusing it means Every tree has same number of Childrens as Its parents.**

Or Each children has as many children as I want `Like Windows Directory`

Sorry for My Sub Standard  English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Directory is not N-ary tree, because number of children of every node is not limited (theoretically).

In full N-ary tree every node can have only 0 or N children. Example of full 3-ary tree - there are no nodes with 1 or 2 children:

```
A
  A1
    A11
      A111
      A112
      A113
    A12
    A13 
  A2
    A21
    A22
    A23 
  A3
```

Comment: Nice But What is Windows Directory

Comment: What's about Windows Directory? It is just rooted(oriented) tree.